# Price slider in magento 1.9

Tags: magento, slider, price

hi i am developing an application in magento 1.9.2 and I am trying to install a price slider in my magento rwd theme, the problem is I am not getting price slider module anywhere for magento 1.9 can anyone help me with this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are modules that can handle this, for example: https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation.html

But if you're not willing to pay for the module, you can set a price slider up yourself:

- Firstly, you need a slider input, you can use the simple html input: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp (or you can find a JS library)
- Secondly, you need to use layered navigation in magento, in case you don't know what layered navigation is, you can read this: https://www.manadev.com/documentation/magento-1.x-guides/price-slider-for-layered-navigation/what-is-layered-navigation-in-magento
- Layered Navigation will return you the price ranges through Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Price, use these ranges to modify your range input so that you can have the correct min and max amount, and also possible to modify your ajax calls to send the correct filter data